# Load-balancing of requests in Erlang ssl

Tags: ssl, erlang, load-balancing

Is there any way to have something similar to:

https://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2011-ssl-session-reuse-rfc5077.html#sharing-tickets

using current Erlang ssl implementation?

The above link suggests using shared tickets, but any other suggestions to have load-balancing of ssl requests across the Erlang cluster would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-311

So this feature is currently in the backlog.